# Numpy (or scipy) frequency count along columns in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array like so

```
array([[ 1,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  0]])
```

I'd like to get the max frequency value along each column. For the above matrix, I'd like to get [1, 0, 0] (or [1,1,0], since both 0 and 1 occur twice in the second column).

I've looked into numpy.unique, but it only takes 1D arrays. bincount won't work since I have negative numbers in my array. I also need a vectorized implementation (since I have thousands of rows in the matrix).

Comment: It is a duplicate - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

# Create your matrix
a = np.array([[ 1,  0, -1],
              [ 1,  1,  0],
              [-1,  0,  1],
              [ 0,  1,  0]])

# Loop on each column to get the most frequent element and its count
for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    count = Counter(a[:, i])
    count.most_common(1)
```

**Output** :

```
[(1, 2)] # In first column : 1 appears most often (twice)
[(0, 2)] # In second column : 0 appears twice
[(0, 2)] # In third column : 0 appears twice also
```

Comment: I don't think Counter is vectorized. It is extremely slow according to many tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick in using `np.bincount` to facilitate negative numbers:

```
>>> c = np.array([1,  1, -1,  0]) #array with negative number
>>> d = c - c.min() + 1 #make a fake array where minimum is 1, we know the offset to be c.min() - 1
>>> freq = np.bincount(d) # count frequency
>>> freq
array([0, 1, 1, 2]) #the output frequency array of the fake array, NOTE that each frequency is also the frequency of the original array shifted by c.min() - 1 positions
>>> np.argmax(freq) + c.min() - 1 #no add back the offsets since d was just a fake array
1
```

Now, armed with this trick, you could loop through each column to find the most frequent element. However, admittedly this solution is not vectorised. As 
 @Jesse Butterfield pointed out, the other post uses `scipy.stats.mode` to handle this case, but it has been criticised for being slow on large matrix with lots of unique elements. The most optimal way is probably best left for empirical trails.

Comment: Yes - scipy stats.mode solves it. Thanks for the neat trick though.